# Determining if the customer has orders

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, xpath, xmldatasource

There is an xml dump of the Northwind database [here](http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=OIkB-WpG_U2SMrg5mv9WULzs0lQ&cid=QOKFVgcrBJQ&s=northwind&mp=0&ml=1&me=1&md=1&filterChecked=false&browser=Default#L2).

Document structure is something like:

```
<NorthWind>
    <Customers></Customers>
    <Customers></Customers>
    .
    .
    .
    <Orders></Orders>
    <Orders></Orders>
    .
    .
    .
</NorthWind>
```

Each Customers tag will hold one customer information. Now while I select all Customers how do I furnish a field such that it indicates whether the customer has orders or not; something like a boolean field

Comment: So, What is the source XML document (a small sample, please) and which exactly nodes do you want to select from this source XML document? If you don't provide these, then the question shouldn't be tagged as "xpath".

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

To find all customers which don't have orders use this XPath:

```
/*/Customers[not(../Orders/CustomerID = CustomerID)]
```

These are Customers with `CustomerID` = `FISSA` and `PARIS`.